# Compiler warning at NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, core-data

Why do I receive following compiler warning:

```
Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSManagedObject *' to parameter of type 'ToDoItem *'
```

at the last line of this method?:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.detailViewController.editToDoItem = object;
}
```

ToDoItem is a NSManagedObject subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.detailViewController.editToDoItem` expects a `ToDoItem` object, so you cannot
pass an object of the `NSManagedObject` *superclass*:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ToDoItem *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.detailViewController.editToDoItem = object;
}
```

Comment: you are right, but should I also assign here the attribute values to be shown in detailViewController, then now it opens with blank values...or are them automatically passed included in ToDoItem *object? I guess the current attribute values for object should be shown in detailViewController..but they are not shown..

Comment: @mvasco: Passing the object to the detail view controller should be fine. Did you check that `self.detailViewController` is correctly set, and not `nil`?

Comment: everything is working fine, I should change some code lines in detail view controller....it is fine now, thank you as always Martin.